# Garbage variable left by temporary pointer of realloc

Tags: c

When using realloc, it's better to check against possible null pointers, as:

```
int *tempPtr=realloc(ptr1,size);
if(tempPtr==NULL){
  fprintf(stderr,"Error allocating memory at line %d\n",__LINE__);
  exit(-1);
}
ptr1=tempPtr;
```

The problem with this approach is that it creates a new variable and if this isn't inside a quick temporary block, it will only be destroyed when the program ends.

Is there any way to destroy this variable?

Comment: Why isn't this scoped, as in inside a function? Variables are only "destroyed" when they fall out of scope.

Comment: If you are worried about an extra `tempPtr` then don't be. The compiler will be smart enough to throw that away when it is no longer needed.

Comment: It is inside the main function, of course. I'm just worried I'm creating too many variables just to hold a temporary address (which will be copied to the permanent one). It's not memory that's the problem, since they point to the same place, but that variable will still take space in memory.

Comment: *that variable will still take space in memory*. No it almost certainly won't. It's likely the compiler won't even use any memory for it and will store it in a register instead.

Comment: I would not worry about a single pointer, typically 8 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place these expressions in a block scope of its own. Essentially just encapsulate the expression within braces, ie:

```
{
    int *tmpptr = realloc(ptr1, size);
    if (tmpptr == NULL) {
        panic("allocation failed");
    }
    ptr1 = tmpptr;
}
// Continue executing code here
// note that moving forwards from here, tmpptr is out of scope and cannot be used.
```

Comment: You've created a memory leak here.

Comment: My bad, I fixed now, thanks for pointing it out.